# nix-build failure on chainweb compile

Tags: pact

Trying to install chainweb using nix-build, I've downloaded from the repo

nix-build
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: program 'git' failed with exit code 128
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)

error: while evaluating the attribute 'buildCommand' of the derivation 'chainweb' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:177:11:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/attrsets.nix:225:10, called from undefined position:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/wsyx22606j37gin9nw4rn8zhn1gfdp6p-source/project/default.nix:198:36, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/attrsets.nix:225:16:
while evaluating 'optionalString' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/strings.nix:147:26, called from /nix/store/wsyx22606j37gin9nw4rn8zhn1gfdp6p-source/project/default.nix:198:44:
while evaluating 'concatMapStringsSep' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/strings.nix:64:33, called from /nix/store/wsyx22606j37gin9nw4rn8zhn1gfdp6p-source/project/default.nix:200:7:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/wsyx22606j37gin9nw4rn8zhn1gfdp6p-source/project/default.nix:200:33, called from undefined position:
while evaluating the attribute 'propagatedBuildInputs' of the derivation 'chainweb-0.1.0.0' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:177:11:
while evaluating 'getOutput' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/attrsets.nix:452:23, called from undefined position:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:141:17, called from undefined position:
while evaluating 'callCabal2nix' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:179:32, called from /Users/benjessel/Chainweb/chainweb-node/default.nix:183:22:
while evaluating 'overrideCabal' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/lib.nix:37:24, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:189:8:
while evaluating 'callPackageKeepDeriver' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:155:33, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:189:23:
while evaluating 'overrideCabal' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/lib.nix:37:24, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:156:5:
while evaluating 'callPackage' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:114:22, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:156:20:
while evaluating 'callPackageWithScope' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:74:37, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:114:28:
while evaluating 'makeOverridable' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/customisation.nix:67:24, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:97:8:
while evaluating 'drvScope' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:87:18, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/customisation.nix:69:12:
while evaluating the attribute 'installPhase' of the derivation 'cabal2nix-merkle-log' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:177:11:
while evaluating 'canCleanSource' at /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/lib/sources.nix:99:20, called from /nix/store/pxh6ar7qdnx3w5vhpqpf0d9jr1bxrsy1-source/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/make-package-set.nix:185:18:
program 'git' failed with exit code 128

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of output at least.

Answer (score 1):

All resolved in the next version of chainweb. Now currently challenged on  chainweb-node --node-id=0 --config-file=./scripts/test-bootstrap-node.config as chainweb-node not found after nix-build.

However, I believe the binary does exist given that it is in the nex store /nix/store/9pkbmml73853izic9anzyzg4qmsyb418-chainweb-0.1.0.0/bin/chainweb-node

So either it's a path issue to link to the nix/store unlikely as I believe that's a cache, or needs something in the nix-build config file to copy and move the binary to the chainweb-node folder?

Comment: Now doing nix-env -iA ghc.chainweb -f . to see if it builds the chainweb-node binary in the right place as before it was going into results/ghc/chainweb-node/bin